# How to prevent cmd.exe to hit the network when using double slashes with cscript.exe?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cmd, coffeescript, wsh, execjs

Some background: In my Rails environment I'm using **CoffeeScript** which uses **ExecJS** which uses the **Windows Scripting Host** to execute Javascript files.

Unfortunately I'm experiencing huge delays (> 30 seconds) when my CoffeeScript files are compiled.

Using Process Explorer and Process Monitor I already identified the command line as one of the causes. `cscript.exe` expects its parameters with double slashes:

```
cscript //E:jscript //Nologo //U C:/path_to_coffeescript_compiler.js
```

For some reason `cmd.exe` (not `cscript.exe`!) treats the double slashes as double backslashes and tries to resolve the network name of each parameter which obviously fails, but not after some delay.

Here's a small excerpt of the Process Monitor log:

```
cmd.exe     CreateFile     \\E:jscript\\             OBJECT PATH INVALID
cmd.exe     CreateFile     \\E:jscript \Nologo\\     BAD NETWORK PATH
cmd.exe     CreateFile     \\E:jscript \Nologo \U\   BAD NETWORK PATH
cmd.exe     CreateFile     \\Nologo\\                OBJECT PATH INVALID
cmd.exe     CreateFile     \\Nologo \U\              BAD NETWORK PATH
```

... and so on.

What can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Hmm... I cannot reproduce this (procmon shows no activity regard phony network paths). What happens when you replace the `cscript` with something else, for example `echo`. If really `cmd.exe` does something funny here, it should happen there as well. Also, do you invoke `cscript` from an interactive shell or from a batch file. You might want to post the output of `echo %CMDCMDLINE%`.

Comment: Funny, it doesn't happen with `echo`, or any other executable, but it happens with `wscript.exe`. The command line is generated by `ExecJS`, where it starts `cmd.exe` with the `/c` switch. Also the delay doesn't happen on *every* call. From ExecJS it's almost every time, but from my own command line it happens about half of ever time.

Comment: I assume you did see the actual command line with e.g. Process Explorer, but could it be, that for some reason it generates something like `cmd /C //E:...`, i.e. accidentally leaves out the `cscript.exe`? Also, does the error also happen, when you simply run `cmd /c "cscript //E:jscript //Nologo //U C:/path_to_coffeescript_compiler.js"` from a plain CMD window?

Comment: No, `cscript` is actually there. (Otherwise my CoffeeScript files wouldn't be compiled) Manually calling `cmd /c "cscript  ..."` shows the same behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After I did some more hacking I finally found the problem. The culprit was Comodo Internet Security which injected a DLL into the cmd.exe process which did the lookups:

Help text for the option **Do heuristic command-line analysis for certain applications**:

> Selecting this option instructs Comodo Internet Security to perform heuristic analysis of
>   programs that are capable of executing code such as visual basic
>   scripts and java applications. Example programs that are affected by
>   enabling this option are wscript.exe, cmd.exe, java.exe and javaw.exe.

Thanks to all offering workarounds. The fact that none of these worked guided me into finding the cause :)

Answer (score 1):

I have no understanding of what process is at fault, but you could try to hide the `//` from said process.

**Idea 1)** Put the CSCRIPT command in a batch file and then have ExecJS call the batch file.

**Idea 2)** Delay the appearance of the `//` using a FOR variable

```
for %s in (/) do cscript %s%sE:jscript %s%sNologo %s%sU C:/path_to_coffeescript_compiler.js
```

*Note - This doesn't explain much, but most Windows contexts will accept a `/` in place of a `\`. For exampe, `DIR "C:/"` is equivalent to `DIR "C:\"`.*

Comment: Good ideas, but both did not make a difference. I had high hopes for the `for` variant...